# Get unique max value for each y-axis in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code below I'm appending multiple svg elements and get 3 different charts from it.

The problem I have is that the max value that's evaluated from the `y.domain()` for each y-axis is the max value from all of my data.

Is there some clever way to get the max value for each svg and set that to be the max value for each y-axis or do I have to make 3 different y scales?

Here's the code:

```js
var data = [
 {category: "Apples", total: 10, goal: 8},
 {category: "Oranges", total: 20, goal: 18},
 {category: "Bananas", total: 20, goal: 25},
];

chart(data);

function chart(result) {

 var margin = {bottom: 25, right: 25, top: 25, left: 25},
  width = 180 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 230 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
  .data(result)
 .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

 var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .domain(["Total", "Goal"])
  .padding(.1)
  .paddingOuter(.2)

 var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
  .domain([0, d3.max(result, d => Math.max(d.total, d.goal))]).nice()

 var xAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))
 
 var yAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")
  .call(yAxis);
  
 var total = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("x", x("Total"))
  .attr("y", function() {
   var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()
   return y(d.total)
  })
  .attr("height", function() {
   var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()
   return y(0) - y(d.total)
  })

 var goal = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("x", x("Goal"))
  .attr("y", function() {
   var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()
   return y(d.goal)
  })
  .attr("height", function() {
   var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()
   return y(0) - y(d.goal)
  })

 var text = svg.append("text")
  .attr("dx", width / 2)
  .attr("dy", 15)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function() {
   return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().category
  })
}
```

```html
<meta charset ="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js "></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon that the best idea here is refactoring your code to create specific SVGs based on the data you pass to it. However, given the code you have right now, a *new* idiomatic D3 solution is using [local variables](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables).

Actually, according to Mike Bostock...

> For instance, when rendering small multiples of time-series data, you might want the same x-scale for all charts but distinct y-scales to compare the relative performance of each metric.

... local variables are the solution for your exact case!

So, all you need is to set the local...

```
var local = d3.local();

svg.each(function(d) {
    var y = local.set(this, d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
      .domain([0, Math.max(d.total, d.goal)]).nice())
});
```

... and get it to create the axes and the bars. For instance:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return local.get(this)(d.total);
})
```

Have in mind that you don't need that `var d = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()` to get the datum!

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
var data = [{
    category: "Apples",
    total: 10,
    goal: 8
  },
  {
    category: "Oranges",
    total: 20,
    goal: 18
  },
  {
    category: "Bananas",
    total: 20,
    goal: 25
  },
];

var local = d3.local();

chart(data);

function chart(result) {

  var margin = {
      bottom: 25,
      right: 25,
      top: 25,
      left: 25
    },
    width = 180 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 230 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var svg = d3.select("#chart").selectAll("svg")
    .data(result)
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

  var x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .domain(["Total", "Goal"])
    .padding(.1)
    .paddingOuter(.2);

  svg.each(function(d) {
    var y = local.set(this, d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
      .domain([0, Math.max(d.total, d.goal)]).nice())
  });

  var xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))



  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .call(xAxis);

  svg.each(function() {
    var y = local.get(this);
    var yAxis = g => g
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    d3.select(this).append("g")
      .attr("class", "y-axis")
      .call(yAxis);
  })

  var total = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", x("Total"))
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return local.get(this)(d.total);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return local.get(this)(0) - local.get(this)(d.total)
    })

  var goal = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "orange")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", x("Goal"))
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return local.get(this)(d.goal)
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return local.get(this)(0) - local.get(this)(d.goal)
    })

  var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", width / 2)
    .attr("dy", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function() {
      return d3.select(this.parentNode).datum().category
    })
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js "></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure the data in the slightly different way. Doing this allows you to be more flexible when names change, more fruit types are added, words like `total` & `goal` get changed, etc

Either way, you can loop through the initial array and create a separate SVG (each with their own yScales) for each object in the array.

---

```js
const data = [{
    "category": "Apples",
    "bars": [{
        "label": "total",
        "val": 10
      },
      {
        "label": "goal",
        "val": 8
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Oranges",
    "bars": [{
        "label": "total",
        "val": 20
      },
      {
        "label": "goal",
        "val": 18
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Bananas",
    "bars": [{
        "label": "total",
        "val": 20
      },
      {
        "label": "goal",
        "val": 25
      }
    ]
  }
]


data.forEach((d) => chart(d))

function chart(result) {

  const margin = {
      bottom: 25,
      right: 25,
      top: 25,
      left: 25
    },
    width = 180 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 230 - margin.top - margin.bottom

  const svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

  const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .domain(result.bars.map((d) => d.label))
    .padding(.1)
    .paddingOuter(.2)


  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    .domain([0, d3.max(result.bars.map(z => z.val))])

  const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

  const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .call(yAxis)

  const barEnter = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(result.bars)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", d => (d.label === 'total' ? "steelblue" : "green"))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", (d) => x(d.label))
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d.val))
    .attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d.val))

  const text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", width / 2)
    .attr("dy", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(result.category)
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js "></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Update. If you can't optimise your data structure, you could do it this way

```js
const data = [{
    category: "Apples",
    total: 10,
    goal: 8
  },
  {
    category: "Oranges",
    total: 20,
    goal: 18
  },
  {
    category: "Bananas",
    total: 20,
    goal: 25
  }
]


data.forEach((d) => chart(d))

function chart(result) {

  const margin = {
      bottom: 25,
      right: 25,
      top: 25,
      left: 25
    },
    width = 180 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 230 - margin.top - margin.bottom

  const svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

  const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
    .domain(["total", "goal"])
    .padding(.1)
    .paddingOuter(.2)


  const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
    .domain([0, d3.max([result.total, result.goal])])

  const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.bottom) + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSizeOuter(0))

  const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .call(yAxis)

  const totalBarEnter = svg.selectAll(".total")
    .data([result.total])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "total")
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", (d) => x("total"))
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d))
    .attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d))

  const goalBarEnter = svg.selectAll(".goal")
    .data([result.goal])
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "goal")
    .attr("fill", "green")
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("x", (d) => x("goal"))
    .attr("y", (d) => y(d))
    .attr("height", (d) => y(0) - y(d))

  const text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("dx", width / 2)
    .attr("dy", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(result.category)
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js "></script>



<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/Pyoyve)

Comment: Although I appreciate the effort, having the data drastically change like that is not an option for me I'm affraid. Or appending the charts in a for loop. Still 1+

Comment: Have a look at the 2nd snippet

Answer (score -1):

I would create different y_scale for each variable:

```
 //build unique categories set
 var categories = d3.set(function(d){return d.category}).values();
 //define y scale
 var y_scales = {};
 //loop through categories, filter data and set y_scale on max.
 for (c in categories){
    var filtered_result = result.filter(function(d){if(d.category == categories[c]){return d});

    y_scales[categories[c]] = d3.scaleLinear()
                                .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top])
                                .domain([0, d3.max(filtered_result, d => Math.max(d.total, d.goal))]).nice()
 }
```

Comment: `y_scales[Apples](x)` where `x` is the value you are passing to the scale, i think.

Comment: the most horrible filter lambda I have ever seen, a lot better to do a `find` because you only want 1 object and not an array with only 1 object

Comment: A bit harsh Rio.      So you would do:

Comment: var filtered_result = result.find(function(d){return d.category == categories[c]});